# VC++ Display an image within picturebox causes error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bitmap, openfiledialog

In three ways I tried to display an image within a Windows Forms Picturebox using Visual C++ 2010 Express. The files path I fetch with an `openFileDialog`. Here are the three attempts:

1.

```
pictureBox1->ImageLocation = openFileDialog1->FileName;
```

2.

```
Bitmap^ image1;
image1 = gcnew Bitmap(openFileDialog1->FileName, true);
pictureBox1->Image = image1;
```

3.

```
pictureBox1->Image = static_cast<Bitmap ^>(Image::FromFile(openFileDialog1->FileName));
```

Before the image is displayed finally an error- or info-message pops up. The message window has no name an shows `BM6` (opening a Bimap-Image), *`nothing`* (opening a JPEG-Image) or `?PNG[]` (opening a PNG-Image).

**Question**: How I can avoid those messages when displaying an image within a picturebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my programming issue again on my own. The reason why a `MessageBox` showed those strange messages when an image was opened via `openfiledialog` was the code line `MessageBox::Show(sr->ReadToEnd());`. Probably a part of the Image-Header was displayed in the Box. I don't need it, so the **solution** is to delete or to comment out this line of code.